# Обработка результата запроса json

Tags: php, json, api

Отправляю get запрос к апи, декодирую данные и получаю вот такой ассоциативный массив.
Как с него вытащить результаты ?

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ccy] => EUR [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 28.70000 [sale] => 29.10000 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ccy] => RUR [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 0.38000 [sale] => 0.39000 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [ccy] => USD [base_ccy] => UAH [buy] => 25.50000 [sale] => 25.80000 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [ccy] => BTC [base_ccy] => USD [buy] => 408.5333 [sale] => 451.5368 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например:

```
$obj = $array[0];
echo $obj->ccy;
```